# Is it possible to use the Perspective Grid in this type of illustration?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

I've already taken several illustrations like this to remove the Japanese translation and translate into another language. I use Illustrator for this purpose. I take many scenes with perspectives like this from the image, but I can't use the perspective grid to better position the text. Any tips on how to do use it?

[image]

Comment: I, personally, would draw it flat then add perspective. I would never attempt to initially create it in perspective. (And for the record, I think AI's perspective grid feature is just horrible, absolutely horrible.)

Comment: If the image is raster, you should probably use Photoshop to do this, unless the goal is to vectorize the output. You could do it in PS with the [Vanishing Point](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/vanishing-point.html) filter. You just click each corner of the poster and then you got yourself a gridded area. You can leave the filter workspace and come back to it with the grid still intact. The way you can plaster in other images is by merging multiple layers into one or say rasterizing a text layer and `Ctrl+A`+ `Ctrl+C` and then back in the filter `Ctrl+V` and `Ctrl+T` to adjust.

Comment: That said, the regular Free Transform (Ctrl+T) in PS has a `perspective` mode as well or (`Cmd+Alt+Shift + corner drag`), which might be a simpler way to do it in some cases since you don't have to flatten the layers. You can't perspective warp text layers, but you can if you put them inside a `Smart Object` and then you can still edit the text later if needed.